# Valid Mountain Array

Tags: python, arrays, c, algorithm

I was wondering if there is a programmatic way to determine if an array has the pattern of a perfect mountain, without valleys. (Example in the image)

Source: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-mountain-array/

[image: example of mountain/not a mountain array]

Edit:

My attempt in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int AscOrDes(int a[], int first, int last)
{
    int i;
    for(i=first; i<last; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>a[i+1])
            return(1);
        else if(a[i]<a[i+1])
            return(2);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int a[1000],n,i,big=0,r1,r2;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>=a[big])
            big=i;
    }
    r1=AscOrDes(a, 0, big);
    r2=AscOrDes(a, big, n);
    if(r1==2 && r2==1 && big!=0 && big!=n-1)
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");
    return 0;
}
```

The above code doesn't work for the following inputs:

```
8
1 3 2 5 4 3 2 0
```

It gives the output:

```
True
```

Even though it isn't a perfect mountain array.

What I have done in my program is check which element is the largest (`big`), and checked if the elements on the left side of the largest element are in ascending order and those on the right side are in descending order (how the mountain should be).

Comment: Please post the *code* not *image* so people can easily use it to reproduce and help you.

Comment: Of course there is, but this is not how Stack Overflow works. You're expected to *try* and, if necessary, present a reproducible code and ask support about *that*.

However, you can see from the graph that a PMA has only one state change between strict increase and strict decrease, while a non-PMA does not.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question with my attempt to solve it too.

Comment: I will go this way - 1) find the peak point by all the ascending ```5```;  2) then from the point check descending (if you notice the number is lesser)...  Done. Straightforward.

Comment: For related questions, search for "unimodal". https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unimodal

Answer (score 6):

Will try this way:

```
def is_moutain(A):
    i = 1

    N = len(A)
    
    while i < N and A[i] > A[i-1]:   # go on if ascending, and more items existing 
        i += 1
        
    if i == 1 or i == N:
        return False
    
       
    while N > i and A[i] < A[i-1]:   # at the descending point...
        i += 1

    return i == N
 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(is_moutain([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1]))    # True
    print(is_moutain([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4]))    # False
```

Comment: This is the same logic I had thought of, but much better implemented. +1.

Comment: I guess we are all good *Mt. climbers*  ... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Python solution using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

def is_mountain(arr):
    return [u for u, _ in itertools.groupby(
        (b - a for a, b in zip(arr, arr[1:])),  # slope as difference
        lambda v: v // abs(v) if v else v       # slope as unit vector
    )] == [1, -1]  # strictly increasing, then decreasing

print(is_mountain([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 0]))  # True
print(is_mountain([0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0]))  # False
```

Given the sample input:

```
[0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0]
```

the first generator (`b - a for a, b in zip(...)`) subtracts each pair of adjacent elements to produce a sequence of the changes in elevation (the individual slopes):

```
[2, 1, 0, 2, -3, -1, -1]
```

The `v // abs(v)` `lambda` expression that's used as the `key` argument to `itertools.groupby` normalizes those by dividing each by its magnitude, producing a sequence of unit vectors (1 for increasing, -1 for decreasing):

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1]
```

`itertools.groupby` combines identical adjacent elements, producing:

```
[1, 0, 1, -1]
```

We can then simply define a "mountain" as a list for which going through the above process results in the exact result `[1, -1]` (all increases followed by all decreases).

Comment: Alternatively `[u for u, _ in itertools.groupby(
        (b > a) - (a > b) for a, b in itertools.pairwise(arr)
    )] == [1, -1]`

Answer (score 4):

Your AscOrDes function is not working properly: it will always exit at the first iteration:

```
int AscOrDes(int a[], int first, int last)
{
    int i;
    printf("Check array from %d to %d\n", first, last);
    for(i=first; i<last; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>a[i+1]) {
            printf("a[%d]=%d > a[%d]=%d, so return 1\n", i, a[i], i+1, a[i+1]);
            return(1);
        }
        else if(a[i]<a[i+1]) {
            printf("a[%d]=%d < a[%d]=%d, so return 1\n", i, a[i], i+1, a[i+1]);
            return(2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I think you can probably evaluate the array more efficiently, something like this --

```
int state = 0;     // 0 = waiting for increase, 1 = incr, 2 = decr

for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i-1] == a[i]) {
        // Equality is an immediate failure.
        printf("False\n"); exit(0);
    }
    if (a[i-1] < a[i]) {
        // We found an increase. This is valid in states 0 or 1.
        if (2 == state) {
            printf("False\n"); exit(0);
        }
        state = 1;
    } else {
        // Found a decrease. This is valid in state 1 or 2.
        if (0 == state) {
           printf("False\n"); exit(0);
        }
        state = 2;
    }
}
// At the end, we must be in state 2 (decrease after an increase).
if (2 != state) {
    printf("False\n"); exit(0);
}
printf("True\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it in Python:

```
array = [3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 19, 6, 3, 2]


def is_strict_mountain(arr: list):
    maxim = 0
    prev = 0
    max_reached = False
    for element in arr:
        if element > maxim:
            maxim = element
        if element <= prev:
            max_reached = True
        if element >= prev and max_reached:
            return False
        prev = element
    return True


print(is_strict_mountain(array))
```

Here is how I would do it in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN_INT -2147483648

typedef enum {
    false, true
} bool;

bool is_strict_mtn(const int *array, int numElements) {
    if (array == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    int max = MIN_INT;
    int prev = MIN_INT;
    bool max_reached = false;
    int count = 0;
    while (count++ < numElements) {
        if (*array > max) {
            max = *array;
        }
        if (*array <= prev) {
            max_reached = true;
        }
        if (*array >= prev && max_reached) {
            return false;
        }
        prev = *array++;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {

    int arr[] = {5, 6, 7, 9, 12, 67, 56, 44, 23, 11, 5, 3, 1};

    if (is_strict_mtn(arr, 13)) {
        printf("The array is a mountain.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("The array is not a mountain.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answers.  Let's avoid using Python built-in *max* as the variable name.

Comment: @DanielHao very good point, changing it now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need keep tracking of increments and decrements
I used array named delta
if there is increment assign delta[i]=1
if there is decrement assign delta[i]=-1
count 1 s if they equal to last-1 then this part has increments
count -1 s if they equal to last-1 then this part has increments

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int delta[1000];

 int AscOrDes (int a[], int first, int last) 
{
 for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)  delta[i]=0;
 int r = 0;
  
 int i;  
     
int c = 0;
           
for (i = first; i <= last && (i + 1) <= last; i++)
       
  {
      
 if((a[i+1] - a[i]) > 0){
     
     delta[i]=1;
 }
 else{
 delta[i]=-1;
     
 }

 
}
  
 
for (i = first; i <= last && (i + 1) <= last; i++)
    
  {
      
 if (delta[i] > 0)
    
 {

c++;
    
}
  
      else if (delta[i] < 0)
    
    {
      
 
c--;
    
 
}
 
}
  
if (c  >= (last - first))
    
return 1;
  
if (c*-1 >= (last - first))

return 2;
  
return 0;

 
}

int main () 
{
  
int a[1000], n, i, big = 0, r1, r2;
  
scanf ("%d", &n);
  
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    
    {
   
scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
    
}
  
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    
    {
     
if (a[i] >= a[big])
    
big = i;
    
 
}
  
r1 = AscOrDes (a, 0, big);
  
 
r2 = AscOrDes (a, big, n - 1);
  
if (r1 == 1 && r2 == 2 && big != 0 && big != n - 1)
    
 
printf ("True");
  
  else
    
printf ("False");
  
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
from numpy import sign

a = [1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 2, 0]

trend = [sign(a[i+1]-a[i]) for i in range(len(a)-1)]
change = [trend[i+1]-trend[i] for i in range(len(trend)-1)]
print(f'{a} is a mountain: {(trend[0] == 1) and (0 not in trend) and (2 not in change)}')
```

---

- `trend[0] == 1` to ensure the list starts by ascending.
- `0 not in trend` to exclude a list with a plateau.
- `2 not in change` to exclude descent followed by ascend.

Example:

- a: `1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2`
- trend: `1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1`
- change: `-1, 1, -2, 2, -2, 0`

Answer (score 0):

Consume the ascending half with `dropwhile`, then consume the descending half with `all`.

```py
from itertools import dropwhile, pairwise

def is_mountain(a):
    return all(a>b for a,b in dropwhile(lambda x: x[0]<x[1], pairwise(a)))

print(is_mountain([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1])) # True
print(is_mountain([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4])) # False
print(is_mountain([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 0]))  # True
print(is_mountain([0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0]))  # False
print(is_mountain([2, 1]))  # True
```

Comment: Fails LeetCode's first example, `[2, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

State-oriented programming: state starts as `"up"`, and becomes `"down"` the first time `a < b` is false.

```py
from itertools import pairwise, starmap

def is_mountain(a):
    def p(a,b):
        return (p.going == "up" and a < b) or setattr(p, 'going', "down") or a > b
    p.going = "up"
    return all(starmap(p,pairwise(a)))

print(is_mountain([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1])) # True
print(is_mountain([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4])) # False
print(is_mountain([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 0]))  # True
print(is_mountain([0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0]))  # False
print(is_mountain([2, 1]))  # True
```

Comment: Fails LeetCode's first example, `[2, 1]`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I just checked, and the description given for a mountain array on that LeetCode page is much more arbitrary than the OP's. For instance, their first condition is "the length of the array is at least 3", which of course excludes `[2,1]`. I've edited to show that I classify `[2, 1]` as True.

Comment: That's not arbitrary but redundant. It's already implied by the requirement to have a strictly increasing and a strictly decreasing part. `[2,1]` is just not a mountain.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's a matter of definitions. The OP appears to define a perfect mountain as "without valleys" and without "increasing but not strictly" parts (plateaus). By that definition, `[2, 1]` is of course a mountain. So is any 1-element array, and the empty array. Leetcode's definition is stricter (and more arbitrary in my opinion) and excludes mountains that don't have an increasing part of length at least 2 and a decreasing part of length at least 2. I've edited my answer to explicitly show that `[2, 1]` was classified as a mountain by my code, but I won't edit my code to exclude it.

Comment: They didn't properly define it themselves, but the link to the full definition is very prominently included in the question and shouldn't be disregarded.